# How to get data between apostrophes Android

Tags: android, regex

I am trying to get substrings from the string which are between apostrophes using regex.
Format of the string: `Duplicate entry 'bla@bla.bl' for key 'email'`.
The regex I am using: `'([^']*)`.

Code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(duplicated);
Log.d(TAG, matcher.group()));
```

I am not also sure about `matcher.group()`, which returns a single string, that matched the whole regex. In my case, it should return two substrings.

Can somebody correct this regex and give me an explanation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `.split()` instead of Pattern Matching. Its simply hard-coding. Do as below:

```
String[] strSplitted = <Your String>.split("`");
```

Then, the strSplitted Array contains the Strings splitted between `.

Comment: Yea, initially I wanted to do it like this but it returns "Duplicate entry ", "bla@bla.bl", " for key ", "email". It is all right but I thought that the regex that returns just "bla@bla.bl" and "email" will be a little bit more time and memory efficient even though I do not know about the efficiency of methods "split()" and "matcher()" :). So are saying that split() is better, ok?

Comment: `Matcher()` fails maximum times because i faced the problem. Try to avoid that. `split()` has very less time complexity than `Regex`. My suggestion is better make use of `split()`

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regex. It is almost exactly like yours but I include the closing single quote. This is to prevent the closing single quote from being used in the next match.

```
'([^']*)'
```

And to get the contents inside the single quotes use a line similar to this:

```
matcher.group(1)
```

Here is a Java example:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(duplicated);
while (matcher.find()) {
    Log.d(TAG, matcher.group(1)));
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this one but the "output" is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far.

Comment: @Husky - According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893875/debugging-pattern-regex-failure-in-in-java-android you need to call find first. Perhaps you can try the sample code in my solution.

Comment: Yeah, I just read the documentation about find() -> "Returns the next occurrence of the Pattern in the input"

Answer (score 1):

Here's my tested solution. You have to call `find`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'");
String duplicated = "Duplicate entry 'bla@bla.bl' for key 'email'";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(duplicated);

String a = "";
while (matcher.find()) {
    a += matcher.group(1) + "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
bla@bla.bl
email
```

Answer (score 1):

I invent my solution like following.

```
int second_index = 0;
String str = "Duplicate entry 'bla@bla.bl' for key 'email'";
while (true) {
    if (second_index == 0)
        first_index = str.indexOf("'", second_index);
    else
        first_index = str.indexOf("'", second_index + 1);

    if (first_index == -1)
        break;

    second_index = str.indexOf("'", first_index + 1);

    if (second_index == -1)
        break;

    String temp = str.substring(first_index + 1, second_index);

    Log.d("TAG",temp);
}
```

Output

06-25 17:25:17.689: bla@bla.bl
06-25 17:25:17.689: email

Comment: I was also thinking about this, but I am trying to write this application in the way that everything is as simple as possible (with minimum number of conditions etc.) so tried to avoid such a solution :). (I am not claiming that your solution is complex or sth., but I just do not simply want to solve such a simple task using so many "if's"). Anyway, thumb up! :)

Comment: @Husky, i have no problem dear. I get this question and until and unless I found solution myself means my custom code which is capable to do customization which I want, i can't sleep. By the way happy that you have checked this. :)